# Combine laravel queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to combine those queries in one? What I need is to get 4 rows spaced by 6 hours from now.

```
$data1 = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR')
        ->first();

$data2 = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR')
        ->first();

$data3 = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR')
        ->first();

$data4 = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR')
        ->first();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Not sure how I can be more specific, I posted 4 queries that will return 1 result each, I'm asking if it is possible to have 1 query that will return the same 4 results.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the `DB::union()` method to join multiple queries.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions

```php
$data1 = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR')
        ->limit(1);

$data2 = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR')
        ->limit(1);

$data3 = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR')
        ->limit(1);

$data4 = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereRaw('created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR')
        ->limit(1);

$transactions = $data1
    ->union($data2)
    ->union($data3)
    ->union($data4)
    ->get();
```

Though I can't say whether this is ideal in practice.

Comment: Woops, can't read; I see what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, it was the quickest way I could think of to exclude returning any results from the parent query.  I don't love it, but it is effective.

Comment: Haha yup, it gets the job done! Another way would be `$transactions = TransacoesRecentes::orderBy()->whereRaw()->limit()->union(TransacoesRecentes::orderBy()->whereRaw()->union(...))`, but I'm not sure if that's better or worse... Yours is definitely cleaner.

Comment: Ahh...fair enough.  I wasn't aware that placing `union()` after the conditions worked like that.  Learned something new, thanks.

Comment: No problem :) Sidenote, that pseudo-code is completely untested, but it _should_ work similar to how you posted, only using `$data1` as the base query instead of `TransacoesRecentes::where('id',-1)` (null result set), and you can do nested `union()` or chain `union()->union()` (like you're doing).

Comment: Updated original answer. That makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always collect the output from each query or you could create a small static function in the model extracting the value you need giving as parameter the interval, (using Carbon is better)

```
public static function getItemBeforeInterval ($interval)
{
return TransacoesRecentes::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subHours($interval))
        ->first();
}
```

and in the controller you could collect the data:

```
$data = collect(TransacoesRecentes::getItemBeforeInterval(24),TransacoesRecentes::getItemBeforeInterval(18),TransacoesRecentes::getItemBeforeInterval(12),TransacoesRecentes::getItemBeforeInterval(6))
```